# Adding PHP into Apache web server?

Tags: php, linux, apache

So I installed Apache using the typical commands:

```
./configure
make 
make install
```

Then I downloaded PHP version 5.5.2 and did the same thing, now from command line I get this output:

```
PHP 5.5.2 (cli) (built: Aug 22 2013 10:47:20)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Now I have to tell Apache to use PHP, but I don't have modules/libphp5.so as the manual at http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php says.
Im using SUSE linux by the way.

Edit: libphp5.so came with the php distribution, but if you add it that way it promts this:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 147 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: core_globals_id
```

Comment: The page you link to says that you need to run `./configure` with arguments for both Apache and PHP. Since you say you didn't, it isn't much of a surprise that it doesn't work.

Comment: "using the typical commands" --- these days "typical" is to use your distro's package manager. Unless you understand what you do and realize you need to recompile it for your very own reasons. So what actually linux distro do you use?

Comment: yea those arguments are the default arguments @Quentin

Comment: well you don't have to use PHP as an apache module to have it work together with apache. You can also just use CGI or FCGI which you likely have already compiled (at least the CGI variant I guess). Just first try with those simple things to start. Compiling apache modules should be outlined in the diverse manuals and the technical literature as well. Similar for PHP.

Comment: libphp5.so must be provided by php distribution

Comment: ooh its true its on php distribution! I'll try if it works

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it, actually it was a bad installation.
I did:

```
make clean
make
make install
```

and everything worked fine.

Comment: Bad installation of what? PHP or apache?